# why no data result when using button onclick send function in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, button, onclick

i'm new in codeigniter.

why there no result data in views when i use button onclick function..??

here the html on views1

```
                    <?php $no = 1; ?>
                    <?php foreach($noper as $row): ?>
                    <tr class="paginate"> 
                        <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
                        <td id = "Noper"><?php echo $row->no_per; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->tanggal_perawatan; ?></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onClick="noper(this)">Lihat Detail</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $no++; ?>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

and this jquery ajax function in views1

```
function noper(a){
var no_per=$(a).closest("tr").find("#Noper").html();
$.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url('admin/detper1/view_detail_per1/')?>",
    type: "POST",
    data:{
        noper:no_per
    },
    success:function(data){
        console.log(no_per);
        //alert(data);
        window.location = '<?php echo base_url('admin/detper1/view_detail_per1/')?>'; 
        },
    error:function(xhr,ajaxOption,errorThrown){
         console.log(xhr);
       console.log(ajaxOption);
       console.log(errorThrown);
        }
});}
```

here my controller

```
class Detper1 extends MY_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('admin/detail_model','detail');
}

public function view_detail_per1(){

        $id2 = $this->input->post('noper');
        $this->detail->view_det1($id2);

        $data['noper'] = $this->detail->view_det1($id2);
        $this->load->view('admin/perawatan/detper1_view',$data);
}
}
```

and here my model

```
public function view_det1($id2){

    $this->db->select('no_per,nama_pasien,jenis_perawatan,jenis_penyakit,nama_obat,jumlah_obat,tanggal_perawatan');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('no_per',$id2);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

and this views detper_view1 (for display the result)

```
 <?php
                    $no = 1;
                ?>
                <?php foreach($noper as $row): ?>
                    <tr> 
                        <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->no_per; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->nama_pasien; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->jenis_perawatan; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->jenis_penyakit; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->nama_obat; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->jumlah_obat; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->tanggal_perawatan; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $no++; ?>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

but when i try to edit manually value (inside clause where beside 'no_per') in models with another number id like 1,2 or etc that's work fine and successfull. the result display values by id like i entered earlier.

any can help me or suggest me to fix it..?
thank you before,
best regards

Comment: Are you getting the required data in `no_per` in your javascript code?

Comment: @Zeeshan: yes, when i look into console (f12) in browser, that button actually bring a value from looping table where i click the button earlier. but the value looks like doesn't send to the controller. there no notif an error anything in browser and show the tables in another views modul, but no result. i use codeigniter 3.0.2. thanks for your respon

Comment: To help you in a better way , i am asking you if you are getting your passed value in `noper()` javascript function.Also try echoing that posted value in your controller and look if it shows in your call under network tab in developer options.

Comment: @Zeeshan:no, i don't see anything when i call the paramater with echo in controller. just a table with header, but no data inside table. but when i try to use some code like this in views table looping (without jquery ajax) **<td><a href = "<?php echo base_url('admin/detper/view_detail_per/'.$row->no_per) ?>" class ="btn btn-success">Lihat Detail</a></td>** and i call the value in cotroller like this **$id = $this->uri->segment(4);
  echo"$id";
  $data['noper']=$this->detail->view_det($id);
  $this->load->view('admin/perawatan/detper1_view',$data);**. this successfully. what do u think??

Comment: assume i have two version zeeshan. With jquery ajax and using function URI default from codeigniter(success). Before i using this CI (procedural style), this jquery ajax onclick is working fine, and i can playing with them. And now i'm confusing in CI, hehehe. Thanks before

Comment: Really i am not getting what you are trying to say...Can you please explain clearly

Comment: @Zeeshan: I create two version function of them. in first with function tag **<a href>** (success) and the second function with the jquery onclick(unsolved). before i using CI (prosedural style), the code of jquery is working in my application **(to get value from Noper in <td>)**. sorry, if my english language so bad Zeeshan.

Comment: Ok.So here is what i got from your question.Your `href` call to your controller is working fine & you are facing some issue with your AJAX call..Am I right ? Also what i get from your conversation so far is you are trying to details of clicked record via AJAX when that button is clicked...Correct me if i had taken it wrong

Comment: @Zeeshan: Yes,you right. i want to show details it by value of Noper when clicked the button with ajax. I just try to bug it via firebug in mozilla. actually my ajax is success and get the detail results when i clicked the button, but looks like do not want to show it in main html. I know that problems from firebug in **(show command line popup->POSThttp://localhost/my_url_app)**. in there, i can see the ajax function is working perfectly and show the detail results. maybe i have wrong code in ajax success:function to show the final results. i can't sleep and curious for this problems.. :D

Comment: Ok.that sounds good if you are getting the result.Just try alerting the data in ajax success also you are using `window.location`,you should comment it as it will redirect you & you will loose the result,instead use your result to display wherever required using Jquery...

Comment: hmmm. and then what the conclusion mr Zeeshan..?? i can't use the way to show it anyway..?? or are you have any suggest..??
thanks..

Comment: You tell me where you want to display the returned result ? I am considering you have checked & getting the result in ajax success

Comment: yes mr zeeshan, if you have any some suggestion or another way about this..??

Comment: As you are not answering what i am asking,so to conclude here is what i would do, The case is simple i need to display some data that is returned from my ajax call to some `div` or somewhere on `page`.Simple jquery call after processing that data would `$("#div_id").html(data);`..Thats it ... :)

Comment: i'm sorry, i lost my focus with your ask before. yeahh i know, i ever use the function as your suggest, like a rendering data as i know. no need a refresh page. i will try it. i need to sleep a moment mr Zeeshan.

if i have problem, i'll asking to you again. hehehe

thank you mr Zeeshan.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
<td id = "Noper"><?php echo $row->no_per; ?></td>
```

to

```
<td class = "Noper"><?php echo $row->no_per; ?></td>
```

and in js file

```
var no_per=$(a).closest("tr").find("#Noper").html();
```

to

```
var no_per=$(a).closest("tr").find(".Noper").html();
```

Because the id should always unique

Answer (score 0):

Your `ID` element should be unique.

Please, try to change this parameter:

```
id = "Noper"
```

to this:

```
class = "Noper"
```

And adjust your js reference `[...]find(".Noper")`

Comment: hello Wiliiam, thanks for yours comment. that's still doesn't work william. i try to echo the pramaters like **$id2 = $this->input->post('noper'); echo"$id2";** in controller. there empty values, when i look into console (f12) in browser, that button actually have a value from looping table where i click the button earlier.